# ckeditor replaces what it wants

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor

In a `Razor` View I have a simple textarea

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ckHolder" } })
```

to give to the back-end users a nice html support I am using `cKEditor`, to bind the plug in to the text area I am doing this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("@Html.IdFor(m => m.Text)", {});
```

All works fine, but today I am started to try to implement a tag system.

```
<div class="tag-editor">
 <span class="tag-editor-tags"></span>
 <div class="tag-editor-editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

The rendering is following:

```
<div class="tag-editor-editable ui-autocomplete-input cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_107"><p><br></p></div>
```

But I wouldn't have the editor to the content editable div of tags, why I use the explicity CKEDITOR.replace with id of my textarea and I have this behaviour? It's strange, If I don't use .replace the editor doesn't work at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved, I found the solution on [official documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline)

> Inline Editing is a new technology introduced in CKEditor 4 that
>   allows you to select any editable element on the page and edit it
>   in-place. As a result, the editor can be used to edit content that
>   looks just like the final page.
>   ...
>
> Note that in this case you need to turn off automatic editor creation
>   first by setting the CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline option to true.

So I have just to add this line under .replace

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
```